# Analogue of Pfaffian for metrics that are not positive definite

Tags: differential-geometry

Given a Riemannian metric on an oriented even dimensional real vector bundle, the Pfaffian polynomial applied to the matrix of curvature 2 forms with respect to  orthonormal frame fields piece together to yield to a global form that is cohomologous to the Euler class of the vector bundle.

Is there a corresponding invariant polynomial for metrics that are not positive definite e.g. Lorentz metrics?